# Get Image Path from Images Directory in Supporting Files

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a bunch of images stored in an images directory within my Supported Files directory in Xcode. I want to be able to show one of those images. What is the best way to obtain a path to that image? Do I have to copy them to the Documents directory first? If so, how can I do that?

EDIT: I've tried the following to copy the image from Supporting Files to the Documents folder in the app. It successfully copies, but I can't get the image to show:

```
-(void)findImage:(NSString *)imageName
{

// First, test for existence.
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *appImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",imageName]];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:appImagePath];
if (success)
{
    return;
}
// The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.
NSString *defaultImagePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",imageName]];
success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultImagePath toPath:appImagePath error:&error];
if (!success)
{
    NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
}
self.imageDisplay.image = [UIImage imageNamed:appImagePath];
return;
}
```

Comment: i need some clarification: you have imported images into your project and you are trying to access them, right? if so, google for -imageNamed: in UIImage

Comment: That is correct. I wasn't really sure what to look for so thanks.

Comment: No problem, I added it as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"someImageName"];
```

EDIT:
Some additional information:
-imageNamed: will look through the entire main bundle of the application for an imagefile (preferrably an png) with the filename of "someImageName". You need not worry about its location or its extension, since it will be searched for in the mainbundle. Files that you import through the import-file-dialogue in xcode will be added to he main bundle.

This means:
If i have imported a file called myImage.png, calling `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];`from anywhere in my code will get me a UIImage-Object containing that image. Its amazingly simple, and maybe that startled you a bit ;)

Look it up in the docs if you like:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Trying this now...if I want to do it this way, I'd have to refer to its path, correct? It seems to be doing nothing at the moment. I checked the Documents folder (for the Simulator) and the images aren't present in there. Do I need to copy them?

Comment: @rar - i modified my anwser, too.

Comment: Since I am not using PNG files (there are quite a few, so a bit annoying to rename them all), I'll have to specify the extension, correct?